# python script hangs on importing module with multiprocessing code

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to import a simple module, which uses multiprocessing into my main file. The module using multiprocessing obtains the computed results from an `asyncresult.get()`. When this routine is called via importing the script just hangs and does not continue.

Here is a small example.

**import_test.py** (the module to import)

```
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp

if not hasattr(sys.stdin, 'close'):
    def dummy_close():
        pass
    sys.stdin.close = dummy_close

# simple test function to compute in parallel
def testf(x):
    return x*x

# multiprocessing code
pool = mp.Pool()
results = []
for i in range(0,2):
    results.append(pool.apply_async(testf, [i]))
for i in range(0,2):
    print results[i].get()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

**main.py** (simple script which just imports the code and should print stuff from import_test)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import import_test

print "done"
```

When running the script I can see that the import takes place, but the first time `results[i].get()` (`asyncresult.get()` routine) is called the whole script hangs and does not continue without throwing any error. I have tested this under Mac OS X (El Capitan) and Windows 10 running two obviously different python setups. The result is always the behavior described above.

Everything works fine if I just put the code from the imported module into `main.py` itself. Of course my actual code is more complicated than that and I want to keep the parallel computation in the module to be imported.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I may be coming too late, but I think I have the answer to your problem. I had the same a while back. It stems from how Python handles GIL locks during imports and how it clashes with multiprocessing creating a deadlock.

You should have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html. The problem is the following: Python acquires the GIL lock when doing an import and releases it at the end. Hence, when you run a thread via multiprocessing in your imported module and it needs to acquire the lock, a deadlock happens. That is why I advise you to do multiprocessing in your main file.

If for some reason you absolutely want to do multiprocessing during an import, there is also a solution:

```
 import imp
 if imp.lock_held():
     imp.release_lock()
     # do your multiprocessing stuff
     imp.acquire_lock() # Don't forget this import needs to have the lock acquired at the end of the import
```

If you don't make imp acquire the lock anew, you-ll get a runtime exception.

I hope this reveals helpful for someone.

Comment: Do you have an example of  "import imp"  you have shown above? Do we need to use that on main python script or in the imported script file?

Comment: This is necessary only around the portion that uses multiprocessing in the imported script file.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that your code works when you put it in main.py. Could you try moving your code into a function? The way you have it now, the moment the import is done the code gets executed. This would at least give you control over when to run your code.

import_test.py:

```
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp

def run():
    <your code>
```

In main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import import_test
    import_test.run()
```

Comment: That would be a workaround, but at least my design philosophy is to create certain variables when the file is imported. And some of those variables are created using multiprocessing code. Maybe that is a wrong way of thinking about the whole problem.